Gradle Build Fails Due to Incompatible Variant Matching for Android Plugin
Lib Gradle :

plugins { 
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library) 
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) 
    id("maven-publish") 
}

android { 
    namespace = "com.example.curvedbottomnavlibrary" 
    compileSdk = 34

defaultConfig {
    minSdk = 26

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
viewBinding {
    enable = true
}

}

dependencies {

implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
implementation(libs.material)
testImplementation(libs.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)

}

publishing { publications { create<MavenPublication>("release") { afterEvaluate { from(components["release"]) }

        groupId = "com.example"
        artifactId = "CurvedBottomNavLib"
        version = "1.0.2"

        pom {
            name.set("CurvedBottomNavLib")
            description.set("A curved bottom navigation library for Android.")
            url.set("https://github.com/example/CurvedBottomNavLib")

            licenses {
                license {
                    name.set("The Apache License, Version 2.0")
                    url.set("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt")
                }
            }
            developers {
                developer {
                    id.set("example")
                    name.set("Developer Name")
                }
            }
            scm {
                connection.set("scm:git:github.com/example/CurvedBottomNavLib.git")
                developerConnection.set("scm:git:ssh://github.com/example/CurvedBottomNavLib.git")
                url.set("https://github.com/example/CurvedBottomNavLib")
            }
        }
    }
}

}

Project Gradle:

plugins { 
alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false 
alias(libs.plugins.android.library) apply false }

buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        google() 
        mavenCentral() 
    } 
    dependencies { 
        classpath (libs.androidPlugin) //androidPlugin -> "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1"
    }
 }


libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.5.1"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.9.1"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
androidPlugin = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1"

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
android-library = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }




`I'm encountering an issue when trying to build my Android project using Gradle. The build fails with a variant matching error for the Android Gradle plugin. Here are the details:
Environment:
Gradle version: 8.7
Android Gradle plugin version: 8.5.1
Java version: OpenJDK 1.8.0_252
OS: Linux 4.10.0-28-generic amd64
Error Message: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'CurvedBottomNavLib'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1. Required by: project : project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.5.1 project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.5.1 No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but: - Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8 - Other compatible attribute: - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7') - Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library - Other compatible attributes: - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar) - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8) - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7') - Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8 - Other compatible attribute: - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7') - Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library - Other compatible attributes: - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar) - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8) - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
Try:
Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm. No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 592ms
It seems like there is a mismatch in the Java version compatibility between the required and available variants. The error indicates a problem with finding a runtime-compatible variant for Java 8 while the available variants are compatible with Java 11. Update: I have tried using JDK 11 and JDK 17 as recommended, but I still couldn't resolve the issue.
Question: How can I resolve this variant matching issue to successfully build my project? Any insights or suggestions on configuring the project or resolving the compatibility issue would be greatly appreciated.
`
